# Use of unassigned local variable result - different scenario

Tags: c#

Good Day guys! I'm trying to make solve a programming challenge named NextPrime. Its just basically will return the next number that is prime. for example the input is 8, the return value is 11 since 11 is a prime number. I made my code below and got this Use of unassigned local variable result. The code below is my source code:

```
public static int NextPrime(int num)
{
    int half = num / 2;
    int outer = num * 2;
    int x, y, result;
    for (x = num; x <= outer; x++)
    {
        for (y = 2; y <= half; y++)
        {
            if (x % y == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (y == half)
            {
                result = x;
                x = outer + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If this scenario really different from all the other examples of the use of unassigned variable? Not all your code paths initialize `result`.

Comment: assign a default to result, the compiler doesn't know if your code will reach the else if

Comment: What should return the method on `-1` input  `NextPrime(-1)`? Note that the outer `for` will not be looped

Comment: Ask yourself what should the method return when `x % y == 0` or if the outer loop ends without entering the `else if` block and then set the value of `result` at the beginning to that value.

Comment: Damn! Adding initial value in the result does run my code and return correct answer! Thanks guys! I just want to post my concern here because I know I might encounter this kind of error in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `result` can well appear uninitialized; the easiest example is

```
   var demo = NextPrime(-1);
```

Note, that outer loop `for (x = num; x <= outer; x++)` is *not entere*d and that's why `result` is *not assigned*.

What can you do? Direct approach is to implement `IsPrime` method:

```
  public static bool IsPrime(int x) {
    if (x <= 1)
      return false;
    else if (x % 2 == 0) // we have only one even prime, that is 2
      return x == 2; 

    int n = (int)(Math.Sqrt(x) + 0.5);

    for (int divisor = 3; divisor <= n; divisor += 2)
      if (x % divisor == 0)
        return false; 
   
    return true; 
  }
```

And then use it in `NextPrime`:

```
  public static int NextPrime(int num) {
    if (num <= 1)
      return 2;

    for (int x = num + 1 + num % 2; ; start += 2)
      if (IsPrime(x))
        return x;
  }
```

Comment: This is a better answer +2 if i could

Answer (score 1):

[Compiler Error CS0165](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165)

> Use of unassigned local variable 'name'
>
> **The C# compiler doesn't allow the use of uninitialized variables**. If
> the compiler detects the use of a variable that might not have been
> initialized, it generates compiler error CS0165. For more information,
> see Fields. T**his error is generated when the compiler encounters a
> construct that might result in the use of an unassigned variable, even
> if your particular code does not**. This avoids the necessity of overly
> complex rules for definite assignment.

You need to be *explicit* about what is *returned* if the loops don't run. The *compiler* only goes so far with *static analysis* and doesn't probe whether loops are meaningfully setting values within

```
public static int NextPrime(int num)
{
   int half = num / 2;
   int outer = num * 2;
   int result = 0; // Explicit 
   for (var x = num; x <= outer; x++)
      for (var y = 2; y <= half; y++)
         if (x % y == 0)
            break;
         else if (y == half)
         {
            result = x;
            x = outer + 1;
            break;
         }
   return result;
}
```